# Expand DIV vertically from the bottom to the top

Tags: css, html, expand

I would like to expand a DIV vertically from the bottom to the top without using percents or functions (only css). I have two div but only the second one has a defined height, so I have to fix the rest of the space with my first div.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    #one { position: absolute; width: 100%; background: red; top: 0 }
    #two { position: absolute; width: 100%; background: yellow; bottom: 0; height: 200 }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="one">"DIV 1" has to be stucked to "DIV 2"</div>
  <div id="two">I wanna "DIV 2" determines the height of "DIV 1"</div>
</body>

</html>
```

[You can put the code here to see what I'm getting](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_basic)

The problem is that the red div stay on the top :S

Any help will be appreciated, thanks for your time!
Friendly, Chumpocomon

Comment: Use jsFiddle to show us your code please. I have copied and pasted your code here for you. [http://jsfiddle.net/peduarte/RnKmE/](http://jsfiddle.net/peduarte/RnKmE/).

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your questions correctly, this should be what you're after:

http://jsfiddle.net/peduarte/RnKmE/1/

****EDIT****

I am not sure if you can do it with CSS.
However, I did an example in in jQuery.
http://jsfiddle.net/peduarte/RnKmE/3/

Comment: won't work - if content of #one is too long, it'll disappear behind #two http://jsfiddle.net/RnKmE/2/

Comment: I'm thinking the same - can't be done with css only. Closest you could get is http://jsfiddle.net/RnKmE/4/

Comment: The think is that you can do that in the opposite direction but not from bottom to top. I never saw it that because I'm asking here.

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this in pure CSS is to add only one line of code to your example:

```
#one { height:calc(100% - 200px);}
```

and you're done :)

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/RnKmE/110/)

Answer (score 0):

Write like this:

```
#one { 
  position: absolute; 
  width: 100%; 
  background: red; 
  top: 0; 
  bottom:200px
 }
```

### http://jsfiddle.net/sj2AD/7/

Comment: won't work - if content of #one is too long, it'll disappear behind #two

Comment: Thanks, but if you try to move div#two the first one (div#one) will not change its height. I thinks what I'm looking for cannot be done with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g9N39/)

```
 body,html{ height:100%; }
 #one { height:100%; }
```

Comment: Thanks, but #one is behind #two. Divs can not be hidden between them.

Answer (score 0):

check this out, I think it is what you´re looking for:

[jsfiddle.net/mcverde/XZ253/](http://jsfiddle.net/mcverde/XZ253/)

The script is only to add content on the fly.

```
#uno {
width: 150px;
background-color: rgba(244, 244, 244, 0.59);
font-family: sans-serif;
padding: 5%;
bottom: 10%;
position: absolute;
border: 1px solid #4E4E4E;
    max-height:150px;
    overflow:scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}

#enviar{
width:300px;
    height:100px;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a SUPER old question and you must have found an answer ages ago, but I just found it and took a stab at it using Flex. All you need to do is have a container div displaying in flex.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container #one {
  background: red;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.container #two {
  background: yellow;
  flex-basis: 200px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bksLtm06/